# App crashes after some usage of the barcode plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I added this plugin to my cordova/phonegap project: `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`.

Sometimes it works, but after some tries it starts to crash the app.

I used logcat to get the error, and this is what i found:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.my.app/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I tried to add this activity to my config.xml using this:

```xml
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it get even worse, the app crashes after starting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue...
this package plugin.xml sometimes don't put the these tags on Manifest.xml:

```xml
<activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" /> 
<activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
```

This is why some users remove android platform and add again and claim that the "problem is solved" - after some "android run" or "android prepare" commands, the error occurs again.

I made a Workaround, placing commands on my config.xml :

```xml
 <custom-config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
            <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        </custom-config-file>
```

This tags add the missing activities on application tag at AndroidManifest.xml using this package: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config